# What is wrong with this bit of code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to augment a matrix with an identity matrix of similar dimensions, why is this bit of code not working?

It keeps giving the error 'vector subscript out of range'

```
for (i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    for (j = matrix.size(); j < 2 * matrix.size(); j++)
        if (i == j % matrix.size())
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
        else
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Comment: What is the type of `matrix`?

Comment: Provide the definition of the matrix

Comment: Or, study your definition of the matrix. You might find something.

Comment: "not working" — that's unfortunate, now please describe the problem.

Comment: Enclose the for loop in braces?

Comment: Very probable that this is wrong: `j < 2 * matrix.size();`

Comment: @Dan Not required, but would definitely make it more readable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a square matrix I think you are initialising j incorrectly?

```
for (i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    for (j = 0; j < matrix.size(); j++)
       if (i == j)
          matrix[i][j] = 1;
       else
          matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Edit: So to augment I think the following to extend the length of the rows 
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix)

```
for (i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    matrix[i].resize(2 * matrix.size())
    for (j = matrix.size(); j < 2 * matrix.size(); j++)
        if (i == j % matrix.size())
           matrix[i][j] = 1;
        else
           matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Comment: thank you for that but for example say i had a matrix 1 1, 1 2 how would i make it so it was 1 1 1 0, 1 2 0 1

Comment: Ah ok augmenting a matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix ok - in that case your code looks close not sure about memory allocation though do you have to extent all your rows to be longer to allow for the augmentation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to resize each row-vector (or row-array maybe) first. Otherwise the cell you try to access will be outside of your row range (and you receive the corresponding error).

You can do this by `matrix[row].resize(2*matrix[row].size());`, where `row = 0 .. matrix.size()-1`.